# how to use session in php?

Tags: php, session

I am creating a login module in php. I am using session variables for that. 
On the top of the file, I write
`session_start();`

Then when my login password is authenticated, I write
`$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["userid"]`

now do I need to do something else as well to ensure that the session that got started sustains?? because as soon as it logs in, it logs out automatically? does it mean the session expires as soon as I log in?? In that case what should I do to make the session sustain??

Comment: The session expires when you close your browser. A Cookie is set for a duration. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: What you do mean by `as soon as it logs in, it logs out automatically`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put session_start(); at the top of page where you will use the session variables.
And be sure you don't unset session in you login script.

Answer (score 1):

No, session is meant to stay between the requests. If you read `$_SESSION['username']` on next request, it will contain the data you saved in previous request. Obviously, you need to put `session_start();` at the beginning of every page you want to interact with it.

Comment: I thought session is more than "between requests" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)

Comment: We're talking about sessions in PHP's meaning, therefore such simplification is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` doesn't start the session, it starts the *session engine*. It must be run on *every* page you want to have access to the session on.

Answer (score 0):

You need `session_start();` at the top of all files you are going to access Session data in

Answer (score 0):

At the top, put `session_start();` also on each page you want to use session, you need this function.

The session sustains as long as you didn't remove the session or close the browser, not sure whether it will expire sometime. 
To check whether you are still logged in, you can access the session using `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`, or the function `isset($_SESSION['username'])` also helps.